# SQL Server : how to delete specific rows data with where condition in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I have a table with some columns and rows. I want to delete some rows contain specific data at specific row.

Ex: the table name is `EXAM`

[image]

I want to delete row 1 and row 3 when input condition string is C.

I did with the statement:

```
DELETE FROM EXAM 
WHERE Comumn2 = 'C'
```

but only deleted Row 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match rows which contain a specific value, use `LIKE` instead of `=`:

```
DELETE FROM EXAM WHERE Column2 LIKE '%C%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way of doing it by using `CharIndex`

```
DELETE FROM EXAM WHERE CHARINDEX('C',Column2)>0
```